# Convert β to & beta; using Javascript (html encoding)

Tags: javascript, jquery, encoding, special-characters, html-encode

I have have to convert user input β to "& beta;" (I am leaving space because SO converts to β) while doing a form submit.  I will take from the query parameter and send to the API.  I looked for many library

This one does not convert.  it works for & to & amp;
http://amalhashim.wordpress.com/2012/10/19/jquery-html-encode-decode/

and

This one convert to different format,
http://www.tumuski.com/code/htmlencode/

But I need & beta;  .

I need a common function to htmlencode all special characters not β alone..

Please help..

Comment: Why do you want to convert a character to an HTML entity before putting it into a URL? URLs aren't HTML.

Comment: I have to get β from Request and send it to the API.  The API does not handle β.  I have to convert β to &beta ; and send to the API through ajax.

Comment: *boggle*, that is one really broken API.

Comment: Ohh.. thank you..  is there any way I can convert β to & beta;  using javascript

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var mystring = $('#inputid').val();
mystring = mystring.replace(/β/g,"& beta;");
```

UPDATE for more characters:

```
var mystring = $('#inputid').val();
var chars = {}

//ALL THE CHARS YOU WANT TO REPLACE
chars["ß"] = "& beta;"
chars["other"] = "& other;"
//..

for(var chr in chars){
   mystring = mystring.replace(new RegExp(chr, 'g'), chars[chr]);
}
```

Comment: Hi its not only for beta I need for all special characters.. sorry for not clear in my question, i ill update it..

Comment: @Dilip Rajkumar ok, I've updated the answer, let me know if it is useful.

Comment: Thanks Ben.. it is not about specific special characters, its about all special characters..  user can input any special character and I should handle it..